# Dynamically Sized Input Buffer for Console Game in C

Tags: c, console-application

Hey, I'm trying rewrite code in C++ to work in C.  I'm basically just trying to find an equivalent for new and delete in C but it's not quite working, here is my code:

Here's the code in C++:

```
  // Gets the number of events
ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
  // Sizes the eventbuffer based on the number of events
INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[numEvents];

  // Removes from memory:
delete[] eventBuffer;
```

Here's what I have so far in C:

```
  // Event buffer 
INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer;
  // Gets the number of events
ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
  // Sizes the event buffer based on the number of events.
eventBuffer = malloc(numOfEvents * sizeof(*eventBuffer));
  // Removes from memory:
free(eventBuffer);
```

The code above almost works with one error:
Error: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "INPUT_RECORD *"

Answer (score 3):

You just have to cast it --

```
eventBuffer = (INPUT_RECORD*) malloc(numOfEvents * sizeof(*eventBuffer));
```

Of course, someone is going to come along and say that the standard says you don't have to cast the result of "malloc". Obviously, in this case, the standard is irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ code doesn't work. You pass `eventBuffer` to `ReadConsoleInput()` but it's only later that you declare it:

```
  // Gets the number of events
ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
  // Sizes the eventbuffer based on the number of events
INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[numEvents];
```

If `ReadConsoleInput()` needs `eventBuffer` for something, you'll need to declare it before calling the function.

Anyway, the equivalent C code would be:

```
INPUT_RECORD* eventBuffer;
ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);
eventBuffer = (INPUT_RECORD*) malloc(numOfEvents * sizeof(INPUT_RECORD));
```